# With CSS grid, how do I prevent other columns from streching when one column's height gets larger?

Tags: html, css, sass, css-grid

I have a layout like this: (The HTML/CSS is at the bottom of the question)
[image]

Now, when the height of the grid item "One" gets larger, the items "Two", "Three" and "Four" are stretched, like this:
[image]

But what I want is for them to remain in the center together, instead of stretching, something like this:
[image]

How can I achieve this with CSS Grid? Here is the HTML and CSS:

```css
.my-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto auto;
  grid-template-areas: "one two" "one three" "one four";
  gap: 15px;
}
.one {
  grid-area: one;
  height: 300px;
}

.two {
  grid-area: two;
}

.three {
  grid-area: three;
}

.four {
  grid-area: four;
}

/* Just for aesthetics! */
body {
  background-color: #e9e9e9;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px;
}
.card {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-grid">
    <div class="card one">One</div>
    <div class="card two">Two</div>
    <div class="card three">Three</div>
    <div class="card four">Four</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add two additional rows. On the top and the bottom. Also replace the row gap with a bottom margin to avoid empty spaces on the top/bottom

```css
.my-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows:1fr repeat(3,auto) 1fr;
  column-gap: 15px;
}
.one {
  grid-row:1 / span 5;
  height: 300px;
}

.two {
  grid-row: 2;
  margin-bottom:15px;
}
.three {
  grid-row: 3;
  margin-bottom:15px;
}
.four {
  grid-row: 4;
}

/* Just for aesthetics! */
body {
  background-color: #e9e9e9;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px;
}
.card {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-grid">
    <div class="card one">One</div>
    <div class="card two">Two</div>
    <div class="card three">Three</div>
    <div class="card four">Four</div>
</div>
```

Another idea where you can play with the alignment

```css
.my-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr auto 1fr;
  gap: 15px;
}
.one {
  grid-row: span 3;
  height: 300px;
}
.two {
  margin-top:auto;
}
.four {
  margin-bottom:auto;
}


/* Just for aesthetics! */
body {
  background-color: #e9e9e9;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px;
}
.card {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-grid">
    <div class="card one">One</div>
    <div class="card two">Two</div>
    <div class="card three">Three</div>
    <div class="card four">Four</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is brilliant. But isn't there a less hacky way to achieve this? Things like `min-content`, etc. wouldn't work in this case, right? There is no way we can avoid the 2 extra rows?

Comment: @Arad added a second idea

Comment: Nice! I like this one. But by the way, instead of `margin-top: auto`, we can have `align-self: end;`, right?

Comment: @Arad yes, it should give the same result

Comment: Just one problem though, when the item "Two" for example, gets larger in height, the item "Four" (or its enclosing column to be more accurate) follows its height (since they're both set to 1fr), that causes problems if the item "One" is smaller in height than the three columns on the right and it's set to `align-self: center;`, in that case, it wouldn't be visually centered. I added a picture to the end of my question to visualize that. I'd be thankful if you tell me if there is a way around that as well.

Comment: @Arad then it's not a CSS  grid that you need to use but flexbox. You cannot have the centring you want with CSS grid

Answer (score 1):

You may also add  extra rows in your template area.

```css
.my-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto auto;
  grid-template-areas: "one .." "one two" "one three" "one four" "one ..";
  gap: 15px;
}
.one {
  grid-area: one;
  height: 300px;
}

.two {
  grid-area: two;
}

.three {
  grid-area: three;
}

.four {
  grid-area: four;
}

/* Just for aesthetics! */
body {
  background-color: #e9e9e9;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px;
}
.card {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-grid">
    <div class="card one">One</div>
    <div class="card two">Two</div>
    <div class="card three">Three</div>
    <div class="card four">Four</div>
</div>
```

or use margin if its to avoid extra rows:

```css
.my-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr auto 1fr;
  grid-template-areas:   "one two" "one three" "one four"  ;
  gap: 15px;
}
.one {
  grid-area: one;
  height: 300px;
}

.two {
  grid-area: two;
  margin-top:auto;
}

.three {
  grid-area: three;
}

.four {
  grid-area: four;
  margin-bottom:auto;
}

/* Just for aesthetics! */
body {
  background-color: #e9e9e9;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px;
}
.card {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-grid">
    <div class="card one">One</div>
    <div class="card two">Two</div>
    <div class="card three">Three</div>
    <div class="card four">Four</div>
</div>
```